# How to get detailed ExecuteNonQuery error message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm working on my first ever assignment in ASP.NET. It's a website and I work in Visual Studio.

What I can't figure out is how to get a detailed error message to be displayed when ExecuteNonQuery fails.

I'm using OleDb connection, so my guess is I have to use OleDbException or OleDbError to get a detailed error message.

Basically, the question is - how do I update this code to have a detailed error message IF ExecuteNonQuery fails?

```
string v1 = Request["v1"];                                    
string v2 = Request["v2"];
sql2 = "INSERT INTO table(one, two) VALUES('" + v1 + "', '" + v2  + "')";

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
con2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data          Source=C:/Users/BB/Desktop/Database.mdb";
con2.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql2, con2);

try
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
    Response.Write("Error!");
    // detailed error message here?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `catch` to be `catch (Exception ex)` and you can then use `Response.Write(ex.Message)`

Ideally, you would have different catches for different exception types. This is a bucket approach to catching all exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. This suits me, for now :) Reading about those different catches/different exception types at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Change your catch to catch (SqlException ex) and catch (Exception ex)

```
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
            {
                errorMessages.Append("Index #......" + i.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                                     "Message:....." + ex.Errors[i].Message + Environment.NewLine +
                                     "LineNumber:.." + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            WriteToLog(FileLog, "SQL Error message: " + errorMessages.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            WriteToLog(FileLog, "Process has been finished with errors." + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToLog(FileLog, "Error message: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            WriteToLog(FileLog, "Error stack trace: " + ex.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine);
            WriteToLog(FileLog, "Process has been finished with errors." + Environment.NewLine);
```